# What's wrong with my GUI code?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Sorry for the large amount of code but i feel like it was needed.  I was wondering what is wrong with my code.  I'm a beginner when it comes to GUI interfaces.  When ever I run my program the window pops up and when I clicck calculate the whole program freezes and I can't even figure out what's wrong with it.  Do you guys see anything i might have done wrong

```
package my.mortgagecalculation3;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Akira
 */
public class MortgageCalculation3UI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form MortgageCalculation3UI
 */
public MortgageCalculation3UI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    javax.swing.JLabel lblMortgageCalculator = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblLoanAmount = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblInterestRate = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblNumberYears = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblMonthly = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtLoanAmount = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txtInterestRate = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txtNumberYears = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txtMonthlyPayment = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    btnCalculate = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnReset = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnExit = new javax.swing.JButton();

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 109, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 114, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    lblMortgageCalculator.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    lblMortgageCalculator.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblMortgageCalculator.setText("Mortgage Calculator");

    lblLoanAmount.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblLoanAmount.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    lblLoanAmount.setLabelFor(lblLoanAmount);
    lblLoanAmount.setText("Loan Amount :");

    lblInterestRate.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblInterestRate.setText("Interest Rate :");
    lblInterestRate.setToolTipText("");
    lblInterestRate.setName("lblInterestRate"); // NOI18N

    lblNumberYears.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblNumberYears.setText("Years to pay :");
    lblNumberYears.setToolTipText("");

    lblMonthly.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblMonthly.setText("Monthly Payment :");

    txtLoanAmount.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    txtLoanAmount.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtLoanAmountActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txtInterestRate.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

    txtNumberYears.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

    txtMonthlyPayment.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

    btnCalculate.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    btnCalculate.setText("Calculate");
    btnCalculate.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnCalculateActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnReset.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    btnReset.setText("Reset");
    btnReset.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnResetActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnExit.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    btnExit.setText("Exit");
    btnExit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnExitActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(lblMortgageCalculator, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(lblMonthly)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(txtMonthlyPayment))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(lblInterestRate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(lblLoanAmount)
                                    .addComponent(lblNumberYears, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(txtLoanAmount)
                                    .addComponent(txtInterestRate)
                                    .addComponent(txtNumberYears, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 154, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(btnCalculate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(btnReset, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(btnExit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(0, 28, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
            .addComponent(lblMortgageCalculator, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lblLoanAmount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(txtLoanAmount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lblInterestRate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(txtInterestRate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lblNumberYears, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(txtNumberYears, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(45, 45, 45)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lblMonthly, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(txtMonthlyPayment, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 50, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(btnCalculate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 38, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnExit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnReset, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(27, 27, 27))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    System.exit(0);
}                                       

private void btnResetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    txtLoanAmount.setText("");
    txtInterestRate.setText("");
    txtNumberYears.setText("");
}                                        

private void btnCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();        
    double loanAmount = 0;
    double interestRate = 0;
    double numberYears = 0;
    double months;
    double monthlyPayment;
    double numerator;
    double denominator;
    double formula;
    String runAgain = "y";


    while (runAgain.equals("y")) {
        try {
            loanAmount = 0;
            interestRate = 0;
            numberYears = 0;

    loanAmount = Double.parseDouble(txtLoanAmount.getText());

    interestRate = Double.parseDouble(txtInterestRate.getText());

    numberYears = Double.parseDouble(txtNumberYears.getText());

                //if the user enters a negative number print out a error message, if not, continue calculations
 if ((loanAmount <= 0) || (interestRate <= 0) || (numberYears <= 0)) {

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
             "You must enter positive numerical data!",
             "Invalid Data!",
              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    } else {
        //convert the interest rate
       interestRate = interestRate / 100 / 12;

       //the number of years must be converted to months
       months = numberYears * 12;

       //numerator of the monthly payment formula
       numerator = (Math.pow(1 + interestRate, months));

       //denominator of the monthly payment formula
       denominator = ((numerator)-1);

       //the formula equals the numerator divided by the denominator
       formula = ( numerator / denominator );

       //monthly payment calculation
        monthlyPayment = (interestRate * loanAmount * formula);

         //sytem output
        NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        defaultFormat.format(monthlyPayment);
        txtMonthlyPayment.setText(Double.toString(monthlyPayment));

   }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {   
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
             "You must enter positive numerical data!",
             "Invalid Data!",
              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


        }

            }                       

}                                            

private void txtLoanAmountActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                             

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MortgageCalculation3UI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MortgageCalculation3UI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MortgageCalculation3UI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MortgageCalculation3UI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MortgageCalculation3UI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnCalculate;
private javax.swing.JButton btnExit;
private javax.swing.JButton btnReset;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblInterestRate;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblLoanAmount;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblMonthly;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblNumberYears;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtInterestRate;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtLoanAmount;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtMonthlyPayment;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtNumberYears;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Why did someone add all of this extra code?

Comment: other users can edit posts to improve them, adding tags, reformatting, correcting grammar and spelling. It's like a collaborative wiki.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `btnCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` method:

```
String runAgain = "y";

while (runAgain.equals("y")) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

The `while` loop condition always evaluate to `true`. You have to change the variable to something else after the calculation is complete. I think it's better to use a `boolean` instead of a `String` for this condition. I wonder why this is needed: once the calculation is done there's no point in running it again. Present the result to the user. If he wants to run the calculation again, he'll press the button a second time.

Note that you are running your calculations in the UI Thread and that's a bad thing: if they take too long, your application freezes. Maybe you can [take a look at Swing Workers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Comment: I had this program before I had to implement it to a GUI and it worked fine.  In fact, are teacher wants us to do it like this.  I had something very similar to what you said and he took points off.

Comment: I suppose the "runAgain" was read from the console as well, after reading inputs ad providing the result the. The program asked the user what to do, run again or quit. You can set "runAgain" to "n" after the calculations, but this feels wrong anyway even if it works.